# Java Socket & Thread communication missconception, looking for a solution

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, game-engine

So I started my project of a turn-based game with a server & a client application. Each application communicates with the other with a socket that sends Strings through the BufferedReader and PrintWriter classes.

For each application there is a class called "Session" which is a Thread that always listen to the socket with the br.readLine() method and deals with that received string. In the client-side, there is also another class named "RequestSender" that sends strings to the server. This "RequestSender" is not bound to the "Session" Thread, because it sends Strings only when the User make events.

The problem is: in my protocol, when the "RequestSender" sends a request, it waits that the server answers with the "OK" string before acting up on the client (acting like, for example, moving the player). The server receive the request, the server sends "OK", but the "OK" string don't come in the Client "RequestSender" but in the Client "Session" Thread. This all leads to a deadlock, since the method in the "RequestSender" always waits for an "OK" or a "NO".

Have you some idea that could resolve that without changing too much on my work ?

Thank you :)

Here's a part of the code, I don't put all of it would be a pain for all of us.

-------Client------------

ClientSession class:

```
public class ClientSession implements Runnable {

private Socket socket;
private Thread thread;
private BufferedReader br;
private OutputStreamWriter os;
private PrintWriter out;
private Game game;
private LocalPlayer localPlayer;
private RequestHandler rh;
private RequestSender rs;


public ClientSession(Socket socket, Game game) throws IOException {
    this.game = game;
    this.localPlayer = game.getLocalPlayer();
    this.socket = socket;
    this.rh = new RequestHandler(this.game,this);
    this.rs = new RequestSender(this.game,this);

    this.br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
    this.os = new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream());
    this.out = new PrintWriter(os);

    System.out.println("[Client Session] Session created for server with ip: "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

    this.thread = new Thread(this);
    this.thread.start();
}

public void send(String m) {
    out.println(m);
    out.flush();
    System.out.println("[Client Session] Message sent: "+m);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            String request = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("[Client Session] Request received from server: "+request);
            rh.parseRequest(request.split(" "));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

RequestSender class:

```
public class RequestSender {

private Game game;
private ClientSession clientSession;

public RequestSender(Game game, ClientSession clientSession) {
    this.game = game;
    this.clientSession = clientSession;
}

public void move(String direction) throws IOException {
    clientSession.send("MOVE "+direction);
    if (readLine() == "OK") {
        if (direction == "UP") {
            clientSession.getLocalPlayer().moveUp();
        } else if (direction == "DOWN") {
            clientSession.getLocalPlayer().moveDown();  
        } else if (direction == "LEFT") {
            clientSession.getLocalPlayer().moveLeft();
        } else if (direction == "RIGHT") {
            clientSession.getLocalPlayer().moveRight();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("I moved!");

}

public String readLine() throws IOException {
    String string = clientSession.getBr().readLine();
    return string;
}
}
```

The event is fired up in the "Keyboard" class, which launches the move(String direction) in the "RequestSender".

-------------Server-------------

Session class:

Pretty much the same thing as the client Session, including some other features like send request to all the other sessions etc.

RequestHandler:

```
public class RequestSender {

private Game game;
private ClientSession clientSession;

public RequestSender(Game game, ClientSession clientSession) {
    this.game = game;
    this.clientSession = clientSession;
}

public void move(String direction) throws IOException {
    clientSession.send("MOVE "+direction);
    if (readLine() == "OK") {
        if (direction == "UP") {
            clientSession.getLocalPlayer().moveUp();
        } else if (direction == "DOWN") {
            clientSession.getLocalPlayer().moveDown();  
        } else if (direction == "LEFT") {
            clientSession.getLocalPlayer().moveLeft();
        } else if (direction == "RIGHT") {
            clientSession.getLocalPlayer().moveRight();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("I moved!");

}

public String readLine() throws IOException {
    String string = clientSession.getBr().readLine();
    return string;
}
}
```

Comment: You will get unpredictable results if you have two threads reading from the same socket. There's no way to avoid that. Don't have two threads reading from the same socket.

Comment: @immibis Do you have an alternative solution to make the client understand that he's allowed to proceed ? Or I should simply make a second socket in the "Session" Class ?

Comment: Use one reader and one writer. When your reader gets a response then change your client state accordingly.

Comment: You need to redesign your program and/or protocol so you don't need to have two threads reading from the same socket, but I don't know what the best solution for your program will be.